# Facing issue while connecting postgresql10.8 with django2.1.3

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04

I am beginner in django and postgresql , i m trying to connect database but while running 'python manage.py makemigrations' got error :

```
   File "/home/trainee/portfolio/venvportfolio/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
   conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
   django.db.utils.OperationalError: SSL error: unknown protocol
   expected authentication request from server, but received S
```

requirement.txt :

```
Django==2.1.3
Pillow==6.0.0
psycopg2==2.7.4
psycopg2-binary==2.7.4
pytz==2019.1
```

settings.py :

```
DATABASES = {


    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'portfolio',
    'USER': 'username',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '22'
    }

  }
```

[Screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByqBS.png)

Comment: is your port correct? i dont know but that seems not correct, port 22 is used to ssh connection and you are using to connect database, remove that line and try to migrate again\